# default file source for <> in perl

Tags: perl, stdin

I want to read data by <> operator.

It reads data from stdin or from files specified as script's args

But, if no STDIN presented, nor file specified, I want to read data from default file path;

So, it should be like

```
my $file = '';
if ($ARGC) { open $file, '<default.txt'; }
while (<$file>)  # if no ARGs it should be <>
{
   do_all;
}
```

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "no STDIN presented"?

Comment: When running a "cron" job (at least in older Solaris revs) there is no STDIN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<>` operator reads the list of input file names from `@ARGV`.  Thus, one way to set up a default input file name is just to check if `@ARGV` is empty, and if so, push your default file name onto it:

```perl
push @ARGV, "default.txt" unless @ARGV;
```

---

I'm not sure what you mean by "no STDIN presented", but if you mean that you want your script to read from `foo.txt` instead of `default.txt` if invoked as e.g.:

```sh
perl script.pl < foo.txt
```

or:

```sh
cat foo.txt | perl script.pl
```

then you do this by checking whether `STDIN` is reading from a terminal or not, using the [`-t` file test](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html).  If `STDIN` is *not* a tty, it is most likely a pipe or a file, and thus you *should* try to read from it:

```perl
push @ARGV, "default.txt" unless @ARGV or !-t STDIN;
```

Comment: you are right! another good string is push @ARGV, "default.txt" if !@ARGV and -t STDIN;

Answer (score 2):

> But, if no STDIN presented, nor file specified, I want to read data from default file path

I guess that by "no STDIN" you are referring to no piping on perl `STDIN`

```
push @ARGV, "default.txt" if !@ARGV and -t STDIN;
```

Comment: Note that, because of the `!-t STDIN` check, this will not read from stdin if you try to pipe something to it with e.g. `perl script.pl < foo.txt` or `cat foo.txt | perl script.pl`, which may be unexpected. Then again, it's hard to say exactly what the OP really means with "no STDIN presented", so this *might* be exactly what they want.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen but it will read in case of piping. `perl -E 'say 1* !-t STDIN' < /etc/passwd` and `echo | perl -E 'say 1* !-t STDIN'`

Comment: Yes, your code will read from `default.txt` if stdin is not a tty, such as if you pipe something to it. I'm just saying that this is *probably* the opposite of what the OP wants, and you *probably* should remove the `!` from before `-t`.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen tnx for comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
@ARGV = 'default.txt'
   if !@ARGV && !defined(fileno(STDIN));
```

Reads from the specified files, or
reads from STDIN if open, or
reads from `default.txt`.

The aforementioned `-t` test will fail for `script < file` and `foo | script`.

Comment: `perl -E 'say 1* !-t STDIN' < /etc/passwd`

Comment: To those wondering what @mpapec's code does, it demonstrates my claim that `-t` is incorrect: It can return false even when STDIN is open.

Comment: @mpapec, Obviously. But it wasn't clear what it meant.

Comment: @mpapec, You've entered spamming territory. Maybe you should replace your three cryptic comments (that require a fourth comment by another person to explain) with one clear one?

Comment: `-t STDIN` behaves the same whether is piping or `< file` case.

Comment: @mpapec, Yes, I know it also fails for `cat file | script`. I didn't see the point of mentioning two ways in which it failed when one was sufficient. But fine, added to answer.